# Why I can pipe echo into bc, but I can't do the same with printf?

Tags: pipe, echo, printf, bc

I can pipe echo into bc.

But I cannot do the same with "printf": it gives syntax error.

```
❯ echo "100-5" | bc
95

❯ printf "%s" "100-5" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need a **newline**:

```
printf '%s\n' "100-5" | bc
```

In your present situation